# SQL count and sum query

Tags: heidisql

I have this query that shows the model,brand and category of an equipment and also the engineer that installed the equipment,the commission he earned from doing the job and the county where the equipment is installed. I used this query to display distinct models installed by all the engineers so if an engineer installed the same equipment in a county I will display the equipment just once for a county but the same equipment will be displayed again if an engineer installed it in another county. This is my query:

```
select distinct models.model,brands.brand, categories.name, equipments.commission, equipments.engineer_name, counties.name
from equipments
inner join models on equipments.model = models.id 
inner join brands on equipments.brand = brands.id
inner join categories on equipments.category = categories.id
inner join agencies on equipments.agency = agencies.id
inner join counties on agencies.county = counties.id
inner join clients on agencies.client = clients.id
where equipments.engineer!='all'
order by counties.name asc,equipments.engineer_name
```

I want to use count to display how many times an equipment was installed by the same engineer in a county and also use sum to calculate the commission(fee) he gets for installing the same equipment for a "n" number of times.
Eg: I have a "G" brand, model "y", category "z", commission 2 and it was installed in the same county by the same engineer 5 times. For this case i should display: `G, y, z, 2, equipments.engineer_name,counties.name, 5,10( because 5*2=10)`

I already tried to use count(distinct models.model) but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't completely follow your question, but you probably want to use `GROUP BY` to aggregate.  `COUNT` is an aggregation function.

Comment: Yeah, I want to use both group by and count. If you want another analogy imagine being a salesman at a dealership. I want a report for all the Lamborghini dealerships, grouped by county and engineer name all the cars that were sold by the same salesman but displaying just once a car for a salesman even tough he sold 5 Murcielagos.

Comment: Tell us the column or columns on which you want to aggregate.

Comment: I want to use COUNT on model colum from the models table and SUM on the commission table from the equipment table.